# take subset of dataset based on another dataset

Tags: r, dataset

suppose I have one dataset, which is dat1

```
ID  block   plot    SPID    TotHeight
1   1   1   4   44.5
2   1   1   4   51
3   1   1   4   28.7
4   1   1   4   24.5
5   1   1   4   27.3
6   1   1   4   20
17  1   10  1   44.5
19  1   10  1   51
1   1   11  21  28.7
2   1   11  21  24.5
3   1   11  21  27.3
4   1   11  21  20
5   1   11  21  12.88666667
6   1   11  21  7.235238095
7   1   11  21  1.583809524
```

Then I have another big dataset, which is dat2:

```
ID  block   plot    SPID    Species TotHeight
1   1   1   4   BENI    72
2   1   1   4   BENI    55
3   1   1   4   BENI    51
4   1   1   4   BENI    47
5   1   1   4   BENI    49
6   1   1   4   BENI    34
7   1   1   4   BENI    .
8   1   1   4   BENI    51
9   1   1   4   BENI    66
10  1   1   4   BENI    40
11  1   1   4   BENI    24
12  1   1   4   BENI    62
13  1   1   4   BENI    34
14  1   1   4   BENI    49
15  1   1   4   BENI    57
16  1   1   4   BENI    22
17  1   1   4   BENI    76
18  1   1   4   BENI    56
19  1   1   4   BENI    55
20  1   1   4   BENI    29
21  1   1   4   BENI    24
22  1   1   4   BENI    18
23  1   1   4   BENI    65
24  1   1   4   BENI    55
25  1   1   4   BENI    63
26  1   1   4   BENI    57
27  1   1   4   BENI    57
28  1   1   4   BENI    57
29  1   1   4   BENI    45
30  1   1   4   BENI    83
31  1   1   4   BENI    37
32  1   1   4   BENI    56
33  1   1   4   BENI    65
34  1   1   4   BENI    75
35  1   1   4   BENI    51
36  1   1   4   BENI    .
1   1   2   16  PRSE    141
2   1   2   16  PRSE    192
3   1   2   16  PRSE    .
4   1   2   16  PRSE    197
5   1   2   16  PRSE    172
6   1   2   16  PRSE    143
7   1   2   16  PRSE    141
8   1   2   16  PRSE    155
9   1   2   16  PRSE    167
10  1   2   16  PRSE    155
11  1   2   16  PRSE    175
12  1   2   16  PRSE    190
13  1   2   16  PRSE    148
14  1   2   16  PRSE    180
15  1   2   16  PRSE    .
```

My question is how can I take a subset of data from dat2 in which ID, block and plot match those in dat1? And how can I get a subset of data from dat2 in which ID, block and plot do not match those in dat1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `merge` on the columns ID, block, and plot.

Assuming your data are read in named `dat1` and `dat2`, this should be what you want:

```
> merge(dat1, dat2, by = c("ID", "block", "plot"))
  ID block plot SPID.x TotHeight.x SPID.y Species TotHeight.y
1  1     1    1      4        44.5      4    BENI          72
2  2     1    1      4        51.0      4    BENI          55
3  3     1    1      4        28.7      4    BENI          51
4  4     1    1      4        24.5      4    BENI          47
5  5     1    1      4        27.3      4    BENI          49
6  6     1    1      4        20.0      4    BENI          34
```

This essentially performs an inner join in SQL terms on the three columns of interest. Read the help page for merge for left, right, and outer join possibilities if that is also of interest.

Fully reproducible gist [here](https://gist.github.com/1227092)

To get the rows that didn't merge from `dat2`, this hack works. There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but here it is. First, add the parameter `all.y = TRUE`. This specifies a right join which will return rows from `dat2` which did not merge. Then we can subset on that knowing that the rows that didn't merge will return `NA`'s:

```
subset(merge(dat1, dat2, by = c("ID", "block", "plot"), all.y = TRUE), is.na(SPID.x) == TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chase. How can I get the new dataset from dat2 by deleting the ones which have been merged? Thanks

Comment: @Dan - not sure I'm following you 100%. Are the results of the `merge` function what you want? If so, why not just save that to a new variable, `dat3`? Or overwrite `dat2` if you know you won't need it further.

Comment: Chase, Merge function is what I want. I also want to get a new dataset in which ID, block, and plot do not match those in dat1.

Comment: @Dan - added to answer to address this.