# Subtracting two dataset

Tags: r, dataset, subtraction

I have 2 datasets. One is the parent dataset (A) and other one is a subset (B) of it. I want to create a dataset from A which does not contain rows from B. It should be something like

C=A-B

Both the datasets A and B have same number of columns and column names.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474735/take-subset-of-dataset-based-on-another-dataset

Answer (score 8):

If B is an actual `subset` of A, you can use `setdiff` on `rownames`:

```
sset <- subset(mtcars,cyl==4)
mtcars[setdiff(rownames(mtcars),rownames(sset)),]
```

Comment: Very nice.  Just to note that this works because duplicate row names aren't allowed (even if you set `check.names = FALSE` when you create the data frame).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to convert it into a string for comparing, i.e Do exact matches
you can try this out

```
a <- data.frame(t(matrix(1:12,3,4)))
b <- data.frame(t(matrix(7:21,3,5)))
a[!apply(a,1,FUN=function(y){any(apply(b,1,FUN=function(x){all(x==y)}))}),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might do the trick:

```
C <- A[!(apply(A, 1, toString) %in% apply(B, 1, toString)), ]
```